# why is my font-size on my p tag messing up my inline-block?

Tags: html, css

Everything works except when change my p tag font size it voids the inline block and the elements are no longer side by side.. any ideas why this is?

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NQ4Yv/6/)

HTML

```
<section>
    <div class="first">
        <p>hello this is some text</p>
        <p>and here is some more text</p>
        <div class="ipad"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.first p {
    display: inline-block;
}

.ipad {
    background: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a4/IPad_3.png/220px-IPad_3.png) no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}

section p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

Comment: Works for me. Just make the result quandrant of the fiddle wider and they're all side-by-side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two inline blocks next to each other in a container that's not wide enough for both, so they are wrapping.  That's expected for inline blocks.  Make your browser wide enough and they fit fine.